# Java method affects all other instances of an object

Tags: java, object, inheritance, static, instance-variables

So I'm creating an object-oriented representation of the videogame Fortnite for a project. Let's say a player drinks a shield then that player's personal shield should go up by 25. However I have a problem where if a Player instance drinks a shield, every other Player instance on the map also gets a boost in shield. This works both ways with taking damage and other kinds of healing.

PROBLEM:

```
    System.out.println(broseidon.getCharacter());
    System.out.println(ninja.getCharacter());
    broseidon.getCharacter().heal(miniShield);
    System.out.println(broseidon.getCharacter());
    System.out.println(ninja.getCharacter());
```

OUTPUT:

```
Health: 100, Shield: 0
Health: 100, Shield: 0
Drank minishield
Health: 100, Shield: 25
Health: 100, Shield: 25
```

I've checked for static variables. Not sure what's wrong. Here are the methods I'm using. Each Account instance only has one PlayerCharacter instance.

```
public class Account{
...
    protected PlayerCharacter getCharacter() {
            return pc;
        }
}

public class PlayerCharacter{
...
//HEAL method
    public void heal(HealingItem hi) {
        switch(hi.getType().toLowerCase()) {
        case "bandages":
            if(this.getHealth() < 75) {
                this.setHealth(75);
                System.out.println("Used bandages to heal");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Alert: Bandages cannot be used past 75 health.");
            }
            break;
        case "medkit":
            this.setHealth(100);
            System.out.println("Used medkit to heal");
            break;
        case "minishield":
            if(this.getShield() < 50) {
                this.setShield(this.getShield() + 25);
                System.out.println("Drank minishield");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Alert: miniShield cannot be used past 50 shield.");
            }
            break;
        case "bigshield":
            if((this.getShield() - 50) < 50) {
                this.setShield(100);
                System.out.println("Drank big shield");
            }else {
                this.setShield(this.getShield() + 50);
                System.out.println("Drank big shield");
            }
            break;
        case "chugjug":
            this.setHealth(100);
            this.setShield(100);
            System.out.println("Drank Chug Jug");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If there are more methods/variables you want to know more about please let me know. I thought that 'this' would only work for the specific instance called. Now I'm very confused.

EDIT:
Here is the instantiation of Accounts (each assigned one and only one PlayerObject using the Singleton design pattern). The use of .heal() is shown above in this method:
   broseidon.getCharacter().heal(miniShield);

```
Account broseidon = new Account("Broseidon", true);
        Account ninja = new Account("Ninja", true);
```

Comment: Where are you creating instances of broseidon and ninja?

Comment: yes show that and the usage of the heal() method.

Comment: If something affects *all* instances of a class then there *must* be usage of `static`. Yet your code postage doesn't show how you defined your instance variables. As another remark, you should not use the `switch` statement in your heal method. You should either have a `HealingItem` return a number of how much it heals, or *better* have a method `heal(Player)` in `HealingItem` and implement the logic there so you can easily variate what gets healed in a `Player`.

Comment: Are you sure pc is not static?